# Fluent NHibernate proxy instance failed exceptions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap, fluent

Having an odd problem, the following code works on some computers, but on others it fails:

```
        var user = (from u in userRepository.Linq()
                    where u.Username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
                    select u).Single();

        var allCourses = user.UserCourses.Select(c => c.Course).ToArray();
```

The exception that is thrown is the "Creating a proxy instance failed", "Unable to obtain public key for strongnamekey.pair".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be a permission problem with the machine key. Have a look [here](http://www.programgood.net/2010/07/05/ArgumentExceptionWasUnhandledByUserCodeUnableToObtainPublicKeyForStrongNameKeyPair.aspx) for a resolution.

A longer description of the problem and it's background is available in this [RhinoMocks discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks/browse_thread/thread/26df68ff01567509/5ddebf407228edc4?hl=en&pli=1).

Comment: Seems like this is the problem.